# How to add rows into existing dataframe in pandas? - python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,10,11,12]})
```

How can I insert a new row of zeros at index `0` in one single line?
I tried `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0]]),df)` but it did not work.

The desired output:

```
    a   b   c
0   0   0   0
1   1   5   9
2   2   6   10
3   3   7   11
4   4   8   12
```

Comment: Sorry you want to add a row of zeroes at the beginning but what should the columns be here? 'abc' or '012'?

Comment: @EdChum: Sorry, forgot to add the column names. It should be abc (edited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat the temp df with the original df but you need to pass the same column names so that it aligns in the concatenated df, additionally to get the index as you desire call `reset_index` with `drop=True` param.

```
In [87]:
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0]], columns=df.columns),df]).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[87]:
   a  b   c
0  0  0   0
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  3  7  11
4  4  8  12
```

Answer (score 2):

alternatively to EdChum's solution you can do this:

```
In [163]: pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0]], columns=df.columns).append(df, ignore_index=True)
Out[163]:
   a  b   c
0  0  0   0
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  3  7  11
4  4  8  12
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer more specific to the dataframe being prepended to

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[[0], :] * 0, df]).reset_index(drop=True)
```